# sshuttle VPN works, but breaks website

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, amazon-web-services

Im using this command. It works just fine. Im able to download things from the command line that I previously was not able to

```
sshuttle --dns -vvr user@192.168.1.252 0/0 -x 192.168.1.252
```

The problem is that on this server (that runs in AWS), the one I need to ssh from is also running a Nginx website on port 443.
When the sshuttle service is running, Im unable to load the website in the browser.
I have tried to add 443 with IPTABLES without success

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it. Instead of 0/0, I used the IP range of the server Im attempting download things from. Happy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).